# how to implement Navigation service and dependency injection in xamarin form master detail page

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have been creating a xamarin app with master detail page using MVVM. So later i got realise my app has some limitation like navigating from one view model to another based on business logic.So i followed microsoft docs of enterprise pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/navigation).But unfortunately this is a tabbed navigation.I searched a lot in internet, someone is using prism framework but that i cant choose.

I already added Tiny Ioc container and changed my service as interfaces for dependency injection.

my code

```cs
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public List<MasterPageItem> MenuList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ProfileViewModel();
            MenuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();            

            // Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon  

                    MenuList.Add(new MasterPageItem()
                    {
                        Title = "Home",
                        Icon = FontAwesomeFonts.Home,
                        TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
                    });

                MenuList.Add(new MasterPageItem()
                    {
                        Title = "My Profile",
                        Icon = FontAwesomeFonts.User,
                        TargetType = typeof(ProfilePage)
                    });

        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

                Type page = item.TargetType;
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
                IsPresented = false;            
        }
    }
```

enterprise pattern

```cs
    public partial class MainView : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainViewModel, int>(this, MessageKeys.ChangeTab, (sender, arg) =>
            {
               switch(arg)
                {
                    case 0:
                        CurrentPage = HomeView;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        CurrentPage = ProfileView;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        CurrentPage = BasketView;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        CurrentPage = CampaignView;
                        break;
                }
            });

            await ((CatalogViewModel)HomeView.BindingContext).InitializeAsync(null);
            await ((BasketViewModel)BasketView.BindingContext).InitializeAsync(null);
            await ((ProfileViewModel)ProfileView.BindingContext).InitializeAsync(null);
            await ((CampaignViewModel)CampaignView.BindingContext).InitializeAsync(null);
        }

        protected override async void OnCurrentPageChanged()
        {
            base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

            if (CurrentPage is BasketView)
            {
                // Force basket view refresh every time we access it
                await (BasketView.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
            }
            else if (CurrentPage is CampaignView)
            {
                // Force campaign view refresh every time we access it
                await (CampaignView.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
            }
            else if (CurrentPage is ProfileView)
            {
                // Force profile view refresh every time we access it
                await (ProfileView.BindingContext as ViewModelBase).InitializeAsync(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean this effect ?https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-masterdetailpage-with-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT No.i only need Master detail page navigation.In that, on clicking menu item i want to use navigationservice for navigating to Detail page.To be simple, i want use navigation service and dependency injection with Master Detail page..Thanks

Comment: Okey , like this ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/7h42di2824pcuzy/videoshow.gif?dl=0

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT  yes ..output will look like this..But i want to see your code .and let me understand how did you navigate from page to page and also during the menu item selection..Thanks

Comment: Okey, I have shared my projecrt link here.https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0b4tx1c1p5yjag/AppMasterDetail.rar?dl=0

Comment: Did you manage to solve the IoC issue with Activator? The project linked in the comments doesnt seem to use DI on page navigation does it?